# Running order of JS constructor

Tags: javascript

One question about JS constructor function:

```
var hm = {};
new function(name){
    hm[name] = this;
}("hello")
```

Could anyone give me a little explanation about how this constructor running (such as which part runs first)

Comment: This runs in order top to bottom since the function is being called inline. I don't know how much more explanation is needed.

Answer (score 2):

First `var hm` becomes an Object, then a `new` Anonymous `function` is called with `("hello")` passed into `name` argument. The important thing to understand here is that when you see `()` with or without any arguments after a function name or an Anonymous function, it calls the function. In this case the `new` keyword and the fact that there is a `this` property inside the function makes it a Constructor. `hm` inside the Constructor creates a property based on the `name` argument and assigns the `new` instance itself to `hm[name]`, as `this` refers to each `new` instance. End result is that `hm.hello` or `hm['hello']` now refer to the `new` instance. Of course, all code runs from top to bottom and according to standard order of operations, like String resolution before assignment. Also, note that, this won't work:

```
func('wow');
var func = function(x){
  console.log(x);
}
```

This will work:

```
func('wow');
function func(x){
  console.log(x);
}
```

If you lack understanding of Constructors altogether you should know that a Constructor is used so you can have multiple instances of similar Objects. For instance:

```
function Person(last, first, middle){
  this.lastName = last; this.firstName = first; this.middleName = middle;
  this.said = this.ate = '';
  this.saySomething = function(anything){
    this.said = anything;
    return this;
  }
  this.eatSomething = function(food){
    this.ate = food;
    return this;
  }
  this.didWhat = function(){
    var m = this.middleName ? ' '+this.middleName  : '';
    var n = this.firstName+m+' '+this.lastName;
    if(this.said){
      n += ' said, "'+this.said+'"';
      n += this.ate ? ', and' : '.';
    }
    if(this.ate){
      n += ' ate '+this.ate+'.';
    }
    return n;
  }
}
var Bob = new Person('Small', 'Bob', 'Richard');
Bob.saySomething('This programming stuff is pretty cool.').eatSomething('Some Vegan Food');
console.log(Bob.didWhat());
var Sally = new Person('Jones', 'Sally');
Sally.saySomething("It just takes time, but you'll get it.");
console.log(Sally.didWhat());
```

Remember that the keyword `this` refers to the instance itself. In the example above I have created `Bob` and `Sally` Objects by calling `new` instances of `Person`. By returning `this` within a Constructor method you can chain methods, since the result of the executing method with be the instance itself.

Note that

```
Bob.saySomething('This programming stuff is pretty cool.').eatSomething('Some Vegan Food');
```

is the same as

```
Bob.saySomething('This programming stuff is pretty cool.');
Bob.eatSomething('Some Vegan Food');
```

since, as far as `.eatSomething()` is concerned, `Bob` and `this` are synonymous.

If you just want to access a property, it's like:

```
console.log(Bob.said);
console.log(Bob.lastName);
Bob.said = "Now you're getting it.";
console.log(Bob.didWhat());
```

Comment: I think this answer was good until the last sentence. You can't call a function before it's code exists, that sounds absurd. You can also call a function before its declaration whether or not its been assigned to a var. This works fine: `var alias = func; func(1); alias(2); function func ( x ) { console.log( x ); };`

Comment: @PHPglue Thanks, I think I may not clearly express my question. But this helps, my problem is not fully understand how constructor runs.

Comment: @PHPglue Yeah, sounds better to me.